# How install/uninstall application without user interaction in android without rooting device programatically

Tags: android

I need source code in install/uninstall application without user interaction like it will uninstall in background in non rooted android device. No user interaction .Silent uninstall/install android application.

Comment: Only using ADB, Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49109181/3193627)

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. App must display the permissions it require to the user before installing on the device.