# Un-/Install System apps without rooting the device

Tags: android, root

Is there a way to push apks to the system/app folder without rooting the device?

I found several ways to do it on rooted devices but I am looking for a way to do it without first rooting the device.

If it makes any difference, I want to do it on a Samsung S4 and use twrp as custom recovery.

PS: First rooting and the unrooting is, unfortunately also not an option.

Comment: you cant achieve this without rooting your device bt you can unroot your device after deleting system apps

Comment: thats what I feared. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ***CAN*** uninstall ***WITHOUT*** rooting:

To uninstall an app:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 app--package--name--here
```

Example, uninstalling youtube:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.youtube
```

To list apps by package names:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

To list only system package names:

```
adb shell pm list packages -s
```

Here is a list of system apps that you may want to uninstall:

```
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.chrome &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.sense.browser &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.android.voicedictation &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.sense.socialnetwork.facebook &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.android.providers.downloads &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.aiqidi.nemo &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0  com.htc.sense.socialnetwork.googleplus &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.android.voicedictation &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.sense.linkedin &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.talk &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.apps.books &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.FMRadioWidget &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.fmservice &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.htc.Weather &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.play.games &&
adb shell pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.google.android.apps.magazines
```

Comment: What about installing?

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall any app with adb by using the following command `pm uninstall -k --user 0 NameOfPackage`. You can refer to this article https://www.xda-developers.com/uninstall-carrier-oem-bloatware-without-root-access/

But I'm not sure with the installation part

Answer (score -1):

**Choose one of the following apps :**

1. NoBloat (Free/Non Free)
2. System App Remover (Free/Non Free)
3. App Eater
4. Root App Deleter
5. DeBloater